# Why my wordpress plugin is not working in my themes?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have create an plugin, it's featured image option working in wordpress default theme(twenty thirteen/forteen ) but not working others themes.
Any Idea ?

Comment: Very difficult to predict or resolve the problem without any code or any clue as to what your plugin is doing or it´s structure

Answer (score 0):

> Themes have to declare their support for post thumbnails before the
>   interface for assigning these images will appear on the Edit Post and
>   Edit Page screens. They do this by putting the following in their
>   functions.php file:
>
> `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Enabling_Support_for_Post_Thumbnails

Comment: Dear Das, Thanks for your response.I have already declare this. my plugin's featured image is support wordpress default theme(twenty thirteen/forteen ) but not working others premium and free themes.

Comment: Are you getting the option to upload the image in other themes?

Comment: No. This option i got only WP default theme (twenty thirteen/forteen ).